# Increasing the width of the autocomplete extender list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, autocomplete

I have an ASP.NET AJAX autocomplete extender with `CompletionListCssClass=autocomplete_completionListElement` :

```
.autocomplete_completionListElement 
{   
    width:500px;
    margin : 0px!important;
    background-color : inherit;
    color : windowtext;
    border : buttonshadow;
    border-width : 1px;
    border-style : solid;
    overflow :auto;
    height : 200px;
    text-align : left; 
}
```

But for some odd reason the width of the auto complete list always takes up the width of the textbox even when I set the width to 500px. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I used the `OnClientPopulated="onListPopulated"` property as follows:

```
function onListPopulated() {

        var completionList = $find("AutoCompleteEx").get_completionList();
        completionList.style.width = 'auto';
}
```

Comment: Upvote as this worked for me but just to note that, when declaring the AutoCompleteExtender, I had to include a BehaviorID="AutoCompleteEx" property to allow it be found by $find in the function.

Answer (score 11):

I believe you can also accomplish this by changing

`width:500px;`

to

`width:500px!important;`

Tim Mackey expounds more in [this blog post](http://tim.mackey.ie/ProblemsWithTheAJAXAutoCompleteExtenderArrgh.aspx). Basically you have to use `!important` to override the CSS spit out by the control itself.

Comment: this is a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `min-width` to 500px